# How to order by a DC2Type:json_array subfield

Tags: mysql, arrays, symfony

I'm working in a existing application and I'm asked to order by a child field of a DC2Type:json_array field in Symfony. Normally I would add the field as a column in the table. In this case this is not possible.

We have a `JsonSerializable` `invoice` entity with a normal `date` attribute. But also a `data` attribute which contains the `due_date`. I whould like to order by `data[due_date]` in a Symfony query. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: No, not really.

According to [Doctrine's type mapping matrix](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/types.html#mapping-matrix), `json_array` gets mapped to MySQL's `MEDIUMTEXT` column type, which by default obviously does **not** index its contents as json hence provides little to no performance advantage.  (also, AFAICT, doctrine doesn't provide any json functionality besides converting db json from and to php arrays/nulls)

Maybe you could magically do some string search magic to extract a value to sort by it, but you still wouldn't get the performance boost a proper index provides. Depending on your data this could get noticably slow (and eat memory).

The JSON data type is fairly "new" to the relational database world and mappers like doctrine have not yet fully adopted it either. Extending doctrine to handle this data type will probably take lots of work. Instead you could rethink your table schema to include all the fields *as columns* you want to order by to use all benefits a relational database provides (like indexing).